# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova build fail New project

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I installed the latest node as I need it for different projects but somehow I cannot get any cordova projects to run. If I start a new blank cordova project It fails. I have cleared the cordova cache, installed npm globally and have installed cordova.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>  ENOENT, no such file or directory ''
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : module.js:338
1>  module.js:338
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  throw err;
1>      throw err;
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  ^
1>            ^
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Code\testing\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
1>  Error Cannot find module 'C:\Code\testing\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
1>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
1>      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at startup (node.js:129:16)
1>      at startup (node.js:129:16)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at node.js:814:3
1>      at node.js:814:3
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

If someone has a solution for this I will highly appreciate it.